# Passport authentication get the name of incoming route

Tags: express, passport.js

Currently I have the following configuration for `passport`. Here, each login request is coming from `/login/students`. The `getUserById` function finds the user from a `STUDENT` table stored in database. But login requests can also come from `/login/instructors`, and in that case I would like to find users from `INSTRUCTORS` table. But currently there is no way to check the incoming route's name. How would I know that from which route my login request is coming from? Any help appreciated :)

```js
const initialize = (passport) => {
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'username', passwordField: 'password' }, authenticateUser));
    passport.serializeUser((user, done) => done(null, user.ID));
    passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
        const user = await getUserById(id);
        done(null, user);
    });
};
```

Code for login router:

```js
router
    .route('/login/students')
    .post(
        checkAuth.not, //login only if user is not in current session
        passport.authenticate('local', {
            successRedirect: '/home/students',
            failureRedirect: '/login/students',
        })
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I found out the solution. Just had to set `passReqToCallback` to `true`.

```js
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ usernameField: 'username', passwordField: 'password' }, authenticateUser));
```

Then from `authencateUser`, I could access the `req` param like this:

```js
const authenticateUser = async (req, username, password, done) => {
    console.log(req.url); //prints from which port this login request came
    //blah blah blah do da di do
};
```